# Did human verification get stricter?

Tags: support, captcha, robots

Did something change with the captcha/human verification? I'm seeing this on a daily basis now:

[image: Random GUID in error message when correctly solving captcha]

I think in the past I've seen that at most once in 3 months, and usually when I was doing something like pasting an answer I authored offline and posting it immediately.

These times, though, I've literally spent hours writing and rewriting answers right there in the browser (I've learned a lot today), so I'm curious what is setting off the alarms.

Comment: For some reason "literally spent hours" composing a post seems to trip the captcha, or at least that's something I noticed. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I've done this for years (yes I'm a pathological ---case--- learner)

Comment: I seen mod post about more and more spambot account creation and how work it’s to stop them, I would think it’s related to your issue there as a countermeaure.

Comment: That CAPTCHA is nothing more than counterproductive.